# wlan0 seems to be associated to AP but no internet with raspbian

Tags: networking, wireless

everything is in the title, when I type

```
iwconfig
```

I get:

```
[root@artik ~]# iwconfig 
wlan0     IEEE 802.11-DS  ESSID:"juju" [2]  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.452 GHz  Access Point: F4:F5:24:7F:1A:F8   
          Bit Rate:39 Mb/s   Tx-Power=24 dBm   
          Retry limit:9   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Encryption key:****-****-****-****-****-****-****-****   Security mode:open
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=3/5  Signal level=-69 dBm  Noise level=-94 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:69
          Tx excessive retries:28  Invalid misc:324   Missed beacon:0

p2p0      IEEE 802.11-DS  ESSID:""  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Bit Rate:1 Mb/s   
          Tx-Power=24 dBm   
          Retry limit:9   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=0/5  Signal level=0 dBm  Noise level=0 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:69
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

But when I try to access google, there is no internet...

```
wget google.com
```

With the first command, it seemed to me that I was connected to AP and so should have connectivity.

```
[root@artik ~]# wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: Trying to associate with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 (SSID='juju' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Trying to associate with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 (SSID='juju' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=3 ssid="juju" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=WRONG_KEY
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=3 ssid="juju"
wlan0: Trying to associate with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 (SSID='juju' freq=2452 MHz)
wlan0: Associated with f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=f4:f5:24:7f:1a:f8 reason=0 locally_generated=1
wlan0: WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed - pre-shared key may be incorrect
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=3 ssid="juju" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=WRONG_KEY
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=COUNTRY_IE type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlan0: Failed to initiate sched scan
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed** recheck your *.conf file:

Your .conf file should look like this for wpa2 connections with pre-shared-key:

```
network={
        ssid="home"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk="very secret passphrase"
}
```

In case you want to hide your passphrase your can also use this method here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/278958/243440

Comment: Yes, you are right. dhclient -r works, but dhclient is never ending, I don't know if it is normal, and at the end, I still don't have an ip address

Comment: dhcp is active in your ap? do u know the ip range? you could assign an ip manually as last resort.

Comment: I don't know much about networking :( I'm trying to connect with my 4G. I would prefer to get assigned automatically an ip rather than assigning one manually. I also updated my question with the result of wpa_supplicant, it might help

Comment: **WPA: 4-Way Handshake failed**

Comment: yes, but I don't know why. I added the data with: wpa_passphrase "juju" 11111111 >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf and I have already tested the password and it is correct